# Velocity Not Finding Template

Tags: velocity, filepath

I am trying to get Apache Velocity up and running. I have a `TestClass.class` class in my `my.test.package` package.

```
public class TestClass {
    public static Template getTestTemplate() throws Exception {
        Velocity.init();
        return Velocity.getTemplate("MyTestTemplate.vm");
    } 
}
```

In the same location (`my.test.package`) I have the `MyTestTemplate.vm` file.

The above code causes an exception to be thrown, saying `Unable to find resource 'MyTestTemplate.vm'`. I am not sure what the issue is. Does Velocity not look for the file in the same package? (Note: I originally had the file in the resources folder, but put it under the same folder for testing purposes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, figured it out.

So I figured maybe Velocity was looking in my `WEB-INF/classes` folder. I looked in there only to discover that the `MyTestTemplate.vm` file wasn't there. Turned out I needed to update my Ant script that copied over the resources to include `.vm` files.

```
<include name="**/*.vm"/>
```

Then I needed to update my configuration so that Velocity knew to look in the `classes` folder.

```
VelocityEngine velocityEngine = new VelocityEngine();
velocityEngine.setProperty("resource.loader", "class");
velocityEngine.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");
velocityEngine.init();
```

Then when you get the template, you just need to provide the path after the `WEB-INF/classes` part.

```
velocityEngine.getTemplate("path/to/resource/MyTestTemplate.vm");
```

I am sure there is some way to get the templates off of the file path, but I stopped caring ;)

Comment: Thanks I was missing these two lines:
velocityEngine.setProperty("resource.loader", "class");

velocityEngine.setProperty("class.resource.loader.class", "org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader");